# How to achieve this design in my xml file?

Tags: android, android-xml

How to achieve this design in xml, please help. I described all I want in this attachment:

[image: Attachment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>You can achieve this by overlapping the `TextView`s in a `ConstraintLayout` and adding spaces to the 2nd `TextView` that match the number of letters of the first one.</del> Or you can use one `TextView` and style the first part of the string differently.

As a reference check styling String resources with HTML on the [developer's website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML)

for example:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Title</b>. The rest of your description"));
```

**UPDATE after comments:**

```
<string name="first_item"><b>Title.</b> Rest of the description!</string>
```

then programmatically:

```
String text = getString(R.string.first_item);
Spanned styledText = Html.fromHtml(text, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188534/discussion-on-answer-by-nikos-hidalgo-how-to-achieve-this-design-in-my-xml-file).